# What are these types of problems called?

Tags: radicals

I usually like watching "How-To" or a live video on how to do a math process. So what is the following problem type called? I know it includes radicals, but it's not just radicals, since you get things way simpler when just Google-ing "radicals."

And yes, the parenthesis does finish after 6, I just forgot to screenshot that far accidentally.

$$\sqrt 3(4-2\sqrt 6)$$

Comment: In what respect is that expression a problem? You you want to transform to simpler(?) forms such as $4\sqrt 3-6\sqrt 2$?

Comment: It wants me to simplify. My question isn't how. I'm asking what type of problem is this? If you were a teacher, you'd say "Please study up on _______. What are these types of problems. They aren't simplifying radicals, those are usually a lot simpler and shorter.

Comment: I can't tell what the "type" of problem is. All I can guess from what you've said so far is that you mean "problems with roots in them". Instead of examples, can you just define in words the kinds of problem your talking about?

Comment: Google *simplifying radicals*, and/or *denesting radicals*, etc. You could also change the word *radicals* with *roots*.